# Check when element is double-clicked with middle mouse button

Tags: javascript

```
<div style="width: 250px;
height: 100px;
background-color: Green; 
border-style: solid; 
border-color: Black;"></div>
```

With the code above, I create a green box with a black outline. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4xQF/).

Below, I have a Javascript function *myFunction()*.

```
function myFunction() {
  window.alert("Hello world!");
}
```

How do I get this function to run when the user uses his middle mouse button twice in a row with his mouse in the green box (as quickly as how someone double-clicks with his left mouse button)?

Comment: According to the [W3C Level 3 Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/), only the primary pointer device button (usually the left button but other buttons can be configured to be the primary) can initiate click and double click events. User agents [must not create an event for other buttons](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-dblclick).

Comment: @RobG But no one is stopping [mousedown](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mousedown), right ? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Plain JavaScript 1:

<sup>Cross browser support</sup>

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

var count = 0;
var timeout;

div.onmouseup = function(e){       // thanks RobG, it should be `mouseup`
    if(e.which == 2){
        count++;

        if(!timeout){
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                timeout = undefined;
                check();
            }, 250);
        }
    }else{
        count = 0;
    }
};

function check(){
    if(count >= 2){
        alert('y');
    }
    count = 0;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Znh6y/13/)

#### With jQuery:

<sup>Not working in Firefox 27.0 - use "Plain JS 1"</sup>

```
$("div").dblclick(function(e){
    if(e.which == 2)
        alert('y');
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Znh6y/12/)

#### Plain JavaScript 2:

<sup>Doesn't work in Safari 7/FireFox 27.0 - use "Plain JS 1"</sup>

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

div.ondblclick = function (e) {
    if(e.button == 1) alert('y');
};
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Znh6y/5/)

Comment: @chris97ong Seems to work for me. Try to keep your click's within 300 millisecond.

Comment: Well, actually it does work, but seems to be really glitchy, even after increasing the 2nd argument of the `SetTimeout()` function to 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: @chris97ong Well, actually, it does miss out just sometimes. P.S. Here's the updated version http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Znh6y/2/

Comment: Misses out fewer times now, but still misses out sometimes especially if I spam the middle mouse button.

Comment: @chris97ong Updated my answer, have a look.

Comment: @chris97ong Updated to use vanilla js

Comment: The answer doesn't work at all in Safari 7. If it works in other browsers, it's counter to the current [W3C Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-dblclick), which says only the primary button can initiate a click or double click. A user might configure the "middle" button to be the primary, but then *event.button* will be 0.

Comment: @RobG My earlier version did not use `dblclick`, but was a bit buggy. I will try to update it. Other than that, I think `event.which` would remain constant, so I think I should use it, what do you say ?

Comment: It's not a matter of which event property (probably feature test for button first, then use which if not available), but that browsers aren't supposed to dispatch click or double click events for any button other than the primary. According to tests, current Safari, Firefox and Chrome on Mac OS X comply. AFAIR IE has some a different ideas about button numbering other than primary, but I don't use that feature so not up to speed. [This link](http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html) is a bit old, but hints at issues.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for looking in. I updated my answer just now. Though I will now further investigate the issue. P.S. by the line "current Safari, Firefox and Chrome on Mac OS X comply", do you mean to say that the `click` event isn't fired for middle mouse button ?

Comment: @chris97ong Updated for vanilla js. Now it works much smoother and doesn't miss any dblclick.

Comment: @RobG Thanks again! I updated it and now it seems to work. Please inform if it doesn't work.

Comment: @GaurangTandon—they comply with the Events Specification in not dispatching click events for buttons other than the primary. You are right to use a mouse event as user agents must dispatch one for any button click over an element. However, *mousedown* isn't the correct event, you should use [*mouseup*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseup) as a click-and-hold (e.g. touch interface to start a selection) will cause two mouse downs and your function will see it as a double click when it isn't.

Comment: Also, users can set the speed of double clicks in their system settings, so 250ms may be OK for most but it may be too fast for some. Perhaps 250 as default but configurable if necessary (e.g. optional *delay* argument).

Comment: @RobG Well, actually you are right. However, the same click-and-hold-and-drag problem occasionally happened with `mouseup` too, though it was much better than previous. Updated.

Comment: unfortunately second solution is not working for me :/

Answer (score 0):

Start simple. Add a click handler to you div like this:

```
<div style="width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: Green; 
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: Black;" onclick="myFunction();"></div>
```

Get that working, then search for how to modify the click event to use other buttons

Comment: What I want is when the middle mouse button is double-clicked, not when it is clicked once.

Comment: Use 'ondblclick' and then check the mouse event. The event.button value is 4 for the middle button

Comment: @bitfiddler—only the primary button is supposed to create click and dblclick events, other buttons are not supposed to (see [W3C Events Sepc](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-dblclick)). It seemed to me that browsers used to create events for other buttons, but the spec says no and testing shows modern browsers conform (mostly).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function version of Gaurang's answer, however I can't get it to work reliably on Mac OS (nor is Gaurang's answer reliable). Anyway, it might be useful.

```
// Listener to add
function foo(e) {
  console.log(this.id + ':' + e.button);
}

// Main function
var addNonPrimaryDblclick = (function() {

  var timeout = null,
      count = 0,
      delay = 250;

  // If timeout expires, reset everything
  function checkTimeout() {
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = null;
      count = 0;
    }
  }

  return function(element, listener, newDelay) {

    if (typeof newDelay != 'undefined') delay = newDelay;

    // Add isDoubleClick as listener 
    element.addEventListener('mouseup', isDoubleClick, false);

    function isDoubleClick(e) {

    // A bit of debug
    console.log('button: ' + e.button + '  which: ' + e.which);

    e.preventDefault();

      // 2 is the secondary button, equivalent to 3 in "which" scheme
      if (e.button == 2) {
         count++;

        if (timeout) {

          // If this is second click within delay, reset everything
          // and call listener            
          if (count == 2) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = null;
            count = 0;

            // Set element to "this" in the listener and pass event
            listener.call(element, e);
            return;
          }

        // If no timeout setup, doso
        } else {
          timeout = setTimeout(checkTimeout, delay);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}());

// Example use - set long delay for testing
addNonPrimaryDblclick(document.getElementById('d0'), foo, 1000);
```